# Access data base import to R-installation of mdb tools on Mac

Tags: r, macos, import, mdbtools

The plan ist to import an Access database into R to filter out what I need to make statistical analysis. 
A colleague suggested me the following code:

```
library(Hmisc)
d <- mdb.get('140410_db_vegBY1.mdb')
#(data under #https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ra588lailweynrq/AACRVqMKWtd9Zz7fa94O9CAUa)

# ERROR: sh: mdb-tables: command not found
# Fehler in system(paste("mdb-tables -1", file), intern = TRUE) : 
#  Fehler bei der Ausführung des Kommandos
```

After my search I started to install mdb tools on my mac OS X 10.9.2 following this link: 
http://automatthew.wordpress.com/2008/06/23/how-to-compile-mdbtools-on-mac-os-x-10-4-and-10-5/#comment-124
But it didn't work but the thread seems to be inactive.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 13):

The following steps worked for me.

1. Install the `Hmisc` package for R.
2. Install `mdbtools` version `0.7.1` by `homebrew`: `brew install mdbtools`.
3. Use `mdb.get()` function in the `Hmisc` package to read `.mdb` files into R:

   ```
   library(Hmisc)
   df <- mdb.get('file.mdb')
   ```

Here is my setup and package versions:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] Hmisc_3.17-0    ggplot2_1.0.1   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-3
[5] lattice_0.20-33
```

I should mention that I first tried to install `mdbtools` from source to no avail. I suspect that it was because some dependencies were not installed. See https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools for more information on the dependencies.

Comment: This also works on Linux. Just install mdbtools via your system package mangager. e.g. `sudo apt-get install mdbtools` and then use `mdb.get`.